# SQL backup version is incompatible with this server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I get he following message when i try to restore a database backup to the customers SQL Server 2008.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server
>   running version 10.50.1600. That version is incompatible with this
>   server, which is running version 10.00.4064.

I hade a made a backup of the database and restored in on a server which had version 10.50.1600, then once i finished my dev work i backed it up but now it wont restore on the customers server 10.00.4064.

What are my options now? Is there a way to restore this? can i do a data import or export to the customers server?

Comment: Yeah looks like you've got R2 and they've got vanilla 2008. Easiest would be to script and changes you made and give them that; otherwise I think you're looking at scripting the whole db (and data) which could take hours!

Comment: I have a few hours this morning. I could restore the current DB from the customers server and then do an import of the data from the new version server? hmmm that might work?

Comment: I'm presuming you took a copy of their data at some point, restored it to your machine running a newer version (2008 R2), and now you're trying to restore a backup from your new machine back onto their 2008 server. What I was trying to say was that whatever you needed to do to their data on your end, couldn't you write a script for it and just run that at their end?

Comment: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/SQL-Server-2008-R2-bumps-the-database-version.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Basicly you need to do it by hand and a restore would not work. So you would need to do something of the following:

1. Option1: Script the entire database (tables,views,indexes,procedures,functions,Data,...) with the development verison of the SQL Management studio it works you can also do that with some other tools like Aqua data studio and such. And then just run the sql script on the client server and the whole thing will just get recreated there
2. Option2: setup a sql2008r2 on the client server the dev edition that is free anyway and then just use the Export GUI to transfer it over to the actual server

I would prefer Option1 since it is in my opinion a bit "cleaner"