# How to transfer data between different DB servers - No SSIS, No LinkedServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I tranfer data between different DB Servers, this is a daily job,
i.e:

```
Insert into ServerA..table1
   select data from ServerB.table2.
```

(this is just an example,  the real situation is we select data from many servers, and then do some join, then insert into the destination).

We **can not use SSIS**, we **can not use linked server**,
How can we do this?

btw, this is a daily job, and the data is huge.

Comment: I guess you are looking for this answer on SO:
[What is the best way to auto-generate INSERT statements for a SQL Server table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982568/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-insert-statements-for-a-sql-server-table)

Comment: Hi Yaroslav, many tanks for your reply, my point is, how can we transfer data between different DB Servers without SSIS or linked server. thanks again.

Comment: I got it, you want to do it `on the fly` just from code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple command line BCP script should work for you.  For instance:

```
bcp AdventureWorks2012.Sales.Currency out Currency.dat -T -c -SServer1
bcp AdventureWorks2012.Sales.Currency in Currency.dat -T -c -SServer2
```

Here's [more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your reply. but I think this is a good solution for my situation. I need run sql from serverA on ServerB.   <br /> and  this two SQLs using bcp are run on ServerA and then on ServerB, right?

Comment: Hi David.  The BCP utility can be run from any computer that has network access to the servers, or from the servers themselves.  Please don't forget to mark this as the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The Sync Framework might be worth a look : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question:
[SQL backup version is incompatible with this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750763/sql-backup-version-is-incompatible-with-this-server/11243786#11243786)

The first options from my answer should work for your case

Answer (score 0):

My answer was converted into comment but I'm adding some more info.

I guess you are looking for this answer on SO:

[`What is the best way to auto-generate INSERT statements for a SQL Server table?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982568/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-insert-statements-for-a-sql-server-table)

Once you have the code, just add `USE your_databasename_where_to_copy_data` at the begining, execute and voila

**Edit:**
As you want to do it on the fly, using code, try some of the solutions provided on [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server). Basically it is similar to your code proposal, with some few differences, as for example:

```
INSERT INTO bar..tblFoobar( *fieldlist* )
SELECT *fieldlist* FROM foo..tblFoobar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use C#.net SqlBulkCopy method.